# Submit Major Version from Microsoft Flow, without content approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning, flow

Is it possible to publish a major version of a document using Microsoft Flow, specifically when Content Approval is **disabled**?  I cannot see any relevant Flow actions that might accomplish this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable check in and check out for the document library and use "Check in file" action in Microsoft Flow to publish as a major version.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I'll also note that I didn't have to enable check in/check out on the library. I just added a check out action followed by a check in inside the flow, and a major version was published. Thanks!